# Binding ScrollView Content

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to dynamically bind ScrollView content form ViewModel class.

I have xaml code:

```
<ScrollView
   Grid.Column="1"
   Content="{Binding UserGrid}"
   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
   IsEnabled="False"
   Orientation="Horizontal">
</ScrollView>
```

and ViewModel code

```
class ViewModel : BaseViewModel{
    private Grid _userGrid { get; set; }
    public Grid UserGrid
    {
        get { return _userGrid; }
        set        
        {
            _userGrid = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }
    public override async Task InitAsync()
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            _userGrid = new Grid
            {
                ColumnSpacing = 1,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
            _userGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(GridHeightSize * 4) });
// and adding some content to This grid
         }
     }
```

Of course, I have initialized Binding context in View class

My question is if it is possible to bind this dynamically using this content binding.
Currently, I am getting an error:

,, No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Content', or mismatching type between value and property"

If it is not a proper way of dynamic view binding than what is?

Comment: I think the content must be a `Xamarin.Forms.View` See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.scrollview.content?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: I 've changed it to Xamarin.Forms.View. Still getting the same error

Comment: Ow, ehmmm... well, normally the approach is a bit different. What exactly are you trying to display in your scroll view?

Comment: Why not just create a nested `Grid` in the `ScrollView` xaml and then reference it directly ?

Comment: @Stefan. It is a part of a more complicated view: https://i.imgur.com/4t5LXDP.jpg. I have created it in xaml and cs code and it should be dynamically created based on parameters like users or time. I want to convert it to MVVM just to know how to do it. That's why I want to bind this view because of all its dependencies that should be fetched from service or calculated in a ViewModel

Comment: Okay; in MVVM, typically, you don't have UI elements in the viewmodel. As @Greggz suggest: it's better to put the grid in the xaml view, and render your items with a ItemSource-like control. You then can use templates for the actual xaml, and keep your viewmodel purely a data container

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of databinding is to separate UI from data. Therefore, a data model should never contain any UI elements.

What you can do:

1. Create a new model class, which contains all the data you want to display inside that scroll view, for further reference i call it "CardViewModel" .
2. Add a property of List CardViewData to your ViewModel
3. Delete the InitAsync Task from your ViewModel
4. Make sure both of the view models implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Now in the view consuming your ViewModel, overload the constructor to accept your view model as parameter.
Within the constructor you iterate through the items in the CardViewModel list and create a Grid for each item.

```
public TimeTableView(ViewModel model)
{
    foreach (CardViewModel cardModel in CardViewData)
    {
        CardView view = new CardView(cardModel);
        Container.Children.Add(view);
    }
}
```

Note that "Container" is a placeholder for the element containing the cardviews.

Actually I would suggest that you implement a custom view, which contains all the Elements in order to display the data of your CardViewModel so you can set the binding context of the custom view to your cardview model:

```
public class CardView : Grid
{
    public CardView(CardViewModel model)
    {
        BindingContext = model;
    }
}
```

Also a ScrollView can only contain one element, so you can't simply throw a bunch of elements into it.
You probably need to put a grid inside it and then add the CardViews to that grid.